# uwsgi on Docker and Nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have an amazon EC2 instance (with Amazon Linux) with Nginx installed. I setup a python Flask Application and put that on a Docker container. The Docker file is here:

```
FROM apierleoni/flask-uwsgi:latest
EXPOSE 3001
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001

CMD [ "uwsgi", "--socket", "0.0.0.0:3001", \
               "--protocol", "http", \
               "--wsgi", "wsgi:app" ]
```

docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  integration-app:
    container_name: integration-app-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
```

I can access the Flask application routes over HTTP on port 3001 after running `docker-compose up` command

The Nginx reverse proxying doesn't work. It yields a 502 error. The Nginx configuration looks like this

```
upstream api_server2 {
 server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}



server {
    ...

    location /crm-project-api {
      include uwsgi_params;
      uwsgi_pass api_server2;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: can you check what shows up in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` when you get the 502 error?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is always "this container" and is the wrong value for the upstream.

Comment: @VigneshSP here is what it says:  21315#0: *3284 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 204.107.115.18, server: www.gndhtrn.tk, request: "GET /crm-project-api HTTP/2.0", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3001", host: "www.gndhtrn.tk"

Comment: @DavidMaze the nginx is not installed on docker, its installed on the AWS EC2 instance locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
upstream api_server2 {
 server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}
instead of this add:-
upstream api_server2{
 server integration-app:3001;  // container name
}

CMD [ "uwsgi", "--socket", "0.0.0.0:3001", \
               "--protocol", "http", \
               "--wsgi", "wsgi:app" ]
```

instead of http protocol add uwsgi